# RAM usage on Colab doesn't drop

Tags: python, pytorch, garbage-collection, google-colaboratory, ram

I'm reading a video using `pytorchvideo`. Here's the code for reproducibility

```
from pytorchvideo.data.encoded_video import EncodedVideo
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('path/to/video')
video = EncodedVideo.from_path(path)
video_data = video.get_clip(0, 5)
```

Basically, what I did was to read a video with `EncodedVideo`. Then calling `get_clip(0, 5)` loads the actual data of the video from second 0 - 5. This makes the RAM usage increase by ~1GB.

However, if I put this to a loop

```
while True:
    video = EncodedVideo.from_path(path)
    video_data = video.get_clip(0, 5)
```

then the RAM keeps increasing until the session crashes. I believe the RAM shouldn't increase, since no new variable is created (`video_data` is overwritten)?

Also, if I stop the cell, the RAM won't drop unless I restart the whole session. I tried `del video_data` and `gc.collect()` but it still stays unchanged.

How do I avoid this situation, i.e. loading a same piece of data without increasing the RAM usage, and reduce it without restarting the session?